# Error in opening Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I have Java SE 10.0.1 and downloaded eclipse oxygen 3a.  It was working fine the first time I downloaded and started using it.  But after closing eclipse and trying to reopen, I get an error message with the following code: 1529256145789.log.  Preceding this is the path to find eclipse. P.S. I'm a noob so please talk to me accordingly.

[image]

Thanks!

Update: 
As of today, it is now saying that Eclipse cannot locate companion launcher jars.

Comment: Open the log file into any text editor, and paste the  content in your question...

Comment: your eclipse installation is under the `temp` folder? try re-installing eclipse under `c:\program files`

Comment: @Daniele Why would re-installing Eclipse under `c:\Program Files` resolve this issue? That seems like an unnecessarily drastic approach in the absence of any evidence that it would fix things.

Comment: @skomisa because files in the Temp folder could be deleted by any program? I don't know, any program who frees space on your hard disk usually asks you "do you want to remove files from the Temp folder".

Comment: @Daniele, I think it might have something to do with the selenium files I was trying to configure into the project if that makes any sense.

Comment: @A-L Rather than just describing the problem, please update your post with the actual error(s) you are now seeing in Eclipse (using cut and paste).